# Two transformation groups of the hyperbolic plane are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, group-actions, group-isomorphism

I'm aware that $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})\simeq GL_2(\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{R}^\times$ is isomorphic to the full isometry group of $H^2$, the hyperbolic plane.

I've just been told that $SO(2,1)$, the indefinite special orthogonal group, is also isomorphic to the full isometry group of the hyperbolic plane.

How can I prove this algebraically? That is, how do I find an explicit isomorphism?

I've checked a couple obvious invariants. They're both 3-dimensional, and they are both centerless, so the argument has some credibility. I just can't seem to find an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: One model of the hyperbolic plane is as a sheet of the hyperboloid $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$.

Comment: Look at the trace form, $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ to break up the trace zero space and the scalars. Then conjugation fixes the direct summand of trace zero, and you can treat that as an action by $GL_2$. So...

Comment: @AdamHughes -- That looks like it has all the makings of a **good *answer***.

Comment: Small comment: These groups aren't literally isomorphic, because $SO(2,1)$ is not connected. (The elements that interchange the two sheets of the hyperboloid $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$ are not in the connected component of the identity.) You want $SO^+(2,1)$, the connected component of the identity in $SO(2,1)$. (This is also the thing that acts on the hyperbolic plane by isometries.)

Comment: @mollyerin -- I believe $PGL_2\mathbb{R}$ is not connected either. I believe $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is not in the identity component. I could be mistaken, though.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow Of course you're right; I made a mistake I make all the time of thinking that the determinant of $cA$ is $c \, \text{det} A$. $PGL_2 \mathbb{R}$ isn't connected, and I guess both should be identifiable with the group of isometries of the hyperbolic plane since you can reverse orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\
c&d\end{array}\right)\in PSL(2,{\mathbb R})$ to
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{2}&ab+cd&\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2}{2}\\
ac+bd&ad+bc&ac-bd\\
\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2}{2}&ab-cd&\frac{a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2}{2}\end{array}\right)\in SO(2,1)$$